# How to record glitch footage on a tv?

Tags: editing, video-recording, video-capture, setup, television

I’ve got an analog glitch fx module. It takes rca video input and outputs the same.

The footage is on my pc.

My plan is to connect it as follows.

- Play the footage on my pc.
- HDMI cable from pc to a (HDMI/RCA) converter.
- RCA cable from converter to glitch fx
- RCA cable from glitch fx to tv.

My question is: **is there any way I can record the footage from the tv directly onto something eg memory card, stream to another pc, dvd, some sort of other recorder?**

At the moment, the only way I know for sure is to record the tv with a camera pointed at it.

I think the problem is that the tv will only output on one ‘source’, so for it to play the rca in, I don’t think it will send the video out via hdmi to another pc where I could record it, for example.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: If you are wanting to record the footage, why do you need the TV at all? Why not use RCA cable from glitch fx to recording device?

Comment: @DrMayhem because I need to see it while it records so I can modulate the fx in real time. I think a fix would be a HDMI capture card or a DVD player that connects via HDMI and has an rca in, they might make the quality worse though.